# Extending line to points an unspecified distance using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line, extend

I would like to extend polylines (roads) to existing points (addresses points). Mostly driveways that are very close to the points. Extend Line does not do it since it requires a specified distance and that varies from case to case.

Comment: There are too many potential complications that an infinite distance would not ever return.  Better to specify a kilometer when 10m is needed than let the line run off the edge of the spatial reference.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202180/arcmap-extend-lines-to-points-without-altering-original-geometry/202214#202214. Btw extend line tool extends it to other line in the same f.class.